# What is the use of dbus_g_object_register_marshaller function

Tags: linux, glib, dbus

I am familiar to DBus and its Qt Binding. But I am very new to glib and related stuff. When I am going through the code of some project, I came across "dbus_g_object_register_marshaller" function. Can you please explain me about this briefly in simple terms?

Regards,
Rajeev N Sambhu

Answer (score 0):

Somebody must know the data format on D-Bus to convert it into the desired format. That is what the marshaller is doing for you.
Google for "dbus_g_object_register_marshaller" and you will find many samples for better understanding.